# Libgdx gradle build бесконечный есть запустить дебаг

Tags: gradle, отладка, libgdx

Использую IDEA.
Если запустить дебаг, то приложение запускается, но при этом gradle build бесконечный, из-за чего нельзя использовать hot-swap.
Примечательно что такая проблема только если при установке окружения был отмечен Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю правильно ли, но помогла установка org.gradle.daemon=false в properties